# Seleccionar datos de dos tablas relacionadas

Tags: mysql, sql, django-models

soy nuevo por aquí, estoy realizando un proyecto para completar un curso y tengo una duda sobre hacer una consulta a la base de datos mysql 
En el proyecto tengo dos modelos Reserva y Turnos, donde Turno es foreingKey en reserva.
Modelos:

```
class Reserva(models.Model):
    id_reserva = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Fecha = models.DateField(blank=True)
    TurnosReserva = models.ForeignKey(Turno, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ServicioReservado = models.ForeignKey(Servicio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Turno(models.Model):
    id_turno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Hora = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Ahora, he realizado consultas de manera independiente a cada tabla, de la siguiente manera

```
Reservas = Reserva.objects.filter(Fecha=Fecha, ServicioReservado_id=ServicioId)
Turnos = Turno.objects.all()
```

pero necesito poder hacer una consulta que me devuelva los registros de la tabla Turnos que no existan en la tabla Reserva, de manera de conocer los turnos disponibles 
El problema es que no se como hacer una consulta combinando dos tablas.

Si alguien puede darme una pista, lo agradezco.

Saludos !

Answer (score 0):

Yo al menos lo haría de esta manera en Oracle

```
select t1.* from tabla1 t1 
inner join tabla2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.id  is null;
```

espero se entienda saludos

Comment: Hola Patricio, gracias por tu respuesta

Esta muy clara tu sugerencia para una consulta a la base de datos
Pero ahora que me doy cuenta, más allá que incluí un tag Django, no comente en la explicación que el proyecto esta hecho en Django y se usa pymysql para conectar con la base de datos MySQL

Gracias, saludos !